# Can I register an object as a whole?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am making an insect killing game, where you click the insects and it dies. The insects are movie clips, and have their registration in the center. This means that when I click the insect I have to click it on the center. I want to be able to click the insect wherever and it'll die, can I do that? If so, could you please explain how?

Comment: What do you mean "click it on the center"? It doesn't matter where the registration point is, it should be clickable anywhere.

Comment: Without more info, I can only guess:  Potentially your insect is composed of multiple child objects?  You may need to set `mouseChildren=false` on the top-level insect movie-clip to catch clicks on all children.

Comment: or just add hidden hit area(according to your insects shape it will be rectangle or circle) as sprite in insect movieclip and listen that hidden sprite's mouseClicks to kill insects ...

Answer (score 0):

This works in some cases:

Put an invisible vector shape, (alpha 0) inside the bug movieclip on the top layer above anything else in the movieclip.  Make this the same shape as your bug.  This vector shape will pick up the click, blocking anything below it that might be messing it up.  Often, this approach can solve issues like what you are experiencing.